# Only pickup Hangfire task on server based on the environment (swap slot)

Tags: .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, hangfire

We're running Hangfire for websites using Azure App Services. We also use the wonderful [swapping mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-staged-publishing). That means instead of deploying to production, we deploy a slot and swap it once the deployment is finished.

The problem is, that the swap slot keeps picking up jobs from hangfire.

I want to make sure that only the production slot is actually executing hangfire jobs. The challenge is that the status whether it is production or not happens without an app restart (in both directions).

I can set slot sticky app settings in Azure so with that I can identify whether I am in production mode or not. It just leaves me with the key question:

**How do I enable and disable my app from processing jobs at run-time?**

Comment: Curious, how did you solve the issue ? I'm running into something similar. I send HTTP request to the staging slot, return 204 and Enqueue Hangfire background job. My problem is that the hangfire process for some reason runs on the completely different Azure App (I verified by attaching debugger to the staging slot, it didn't continue there)

Comment: @ihorbond We basically run hangfire on a separate app service, an don't use swapping. just stop,, deploy and start.

Comment: thanks. I figured what was my issue. I was using the same database. Once I created a separate db per slot everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We solved this by separating the Hangfire service out to it's own App Service with a different deployment strategy.
For the Hangfire service we hard stop the service, deploy and then start the service again.

Answer (score 1):

I made a solution to this that doesn't involve having to separate the Hangfire service out as mentioned in the accepted answer.

```
public class SkipProcessingPreProdFilter: IElectStateFilter
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public SkipProcessingPreProdFilter(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public void OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
    {
        if(context.CandidateState.Name == EnqueuedState.StateName)
        {
            //wait for prd server to pickup job, reschedule keep trying
            if (!IsPrdServer())
            {
                context.CandidateState = new ScheduledState(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            }
        }
    }

    private bool IsPrdServer()
    {
        var config = _serviceProvider.GetService<IConfiguration>();
        var isPrd = config.GetSection("APPSERVICE_SLOT")?.Value?
            .Equals("prd", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        return isPrd == true;
    }
}
```

In Startup.Configure do:

```
 GlobalJobFilters.Filters.Add(new SkipProcessingPreProdFilter(app.ApplicationServices));
```

This filter takes each job when it is enqueued and checks if the server has the environment variable of the pre-prd or prd slots. If it is not prd, it reschedules the job for 5 seconds later for it to try again but with (maybe) a new server the next try (it tries again based on your configured polling interval).

This implementation can sometimes take a few retries to finally find the prd server especially if you have horizontal scaling with multiple web servers. If anyone has any ideas to improve it to where I can maybe guide the job to the other server with matching server prefix please comment.

Below is an example of Hangfire configured with a swap slot and configured 2 instances of the Web App using "Scale out". This ends up being 4 servers. Servers that are on the same instance (pre-prd/prd swap servers) have the same name prefix i.e. LN1SDLWK0006LS.

[image]

Or... you could just use a separate connection string per slot like mentioned in a comment.

EDIT: I just thought about it again and if you do a separate connection string per slot, then it is going to still run your app's base list of recurring jobs in the preprd hangfire which could cause many unintended results. It seems better to just prevent the initialization of hangfire and all the base recurring jobs in your app on startup using ENV vars.

Answer (score 0):

Try to configure triggered WebJob, which runs the job every time an API is called, or a schedule is reached. Also, there are 2 configuration setting to stop the WebJob,

•   **WEBJOBS_STOPPED** - Set this setting to 1 to disable running any job (will also stop all currently running jobs).

•   **WEBJOBS_DISABLE_SCHEDULE** - Set this to 1 to turn off all scheduled triggering. Unlike with WEBJOBS_STOPPED, WebJobs can still be manually invoked.

For more details, refer to this article: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs.

Comment: We've used WebJobs in the past and ran into a number of issues and found Hangfire more useful, so I'm hesitant to use WebJobs just for that reason.